# Error: parsing XML: junk after document element

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have got this error on my code but cant workout why, I have tried to solve the issue by searching for an answer on google but haven't come across anything that solves this, the error is showing at

Comment: Where exactly it is showing the error? Which line?

Comment: Where is your closing `</RelativeLayout>`?

Comment: the error is showing at <Button....the closing </RelativeLayout> is there just missed while copying the code over

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash at the end of the initial `<RelativeLayout.../>` and add `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of the document. Tags like this: `<foo/>` are empty.

Comment: ive tried this it didnt work, the error says parsing XML: junk after document element